# Nifi flow doesn't run and shows active threads message

Tags: apache-nifi

Nifi flow has stopped working. Today, on starting the flow all the processors icon turns green, but there is no input or output as GenerateFlowFile shows active threads and terminated threads. This count keeps on increasing or decreasing if I terminate manually or start flow. I also tried to remove the GenerateFlowFile processor and create once again, but same result.
On disabling all processors are disabled but not the GenerateFlowFile.

[image: 1 active thread(1 terminated) message]

[image: On disabling all processors are disabled but not the GenerateFlowFile.]

What is the reason behind this active thread and how to run the flow once again.

Comment: Can you check your nifi-app.log for any errors? Any disks run out of space? How about open file handles with `lsof | wc -l` ?

Comment: @Sdairs I have other NiFi projects which are running fine.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't answer the questions

Comment: @Sdairs The logs had lots of error message "apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Failed to capture component stats for Stats History
java.lang.NullPointerException: null". So I cleared the log file to regenerate and this resolved the issue. I think

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opening the nifi-app.log file and clearing it resolved this issue for me.